# How do I use .htaccess to redirect my entire site to HTTPS apart from one specific page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am using a PHP framework for a new site and have recently implemented SSL. All requests are redirected to HTTPS using .htaccess which currently looks like:-

```
#secure htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On
#Remove index.php being displayed on pages
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|attachments|email|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Everything works fine but I now need to allow access to my site from HTTP in order to get some web accessed cron tasks working. I am struggle to find how to enable **mysite.com/cron** to be accessed from HTTP and not to get redirected for that specific path. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need yuor redirect rule to be **before** your index.php routing rule. THe second thing is you can add a condition or regex so that it **doesn't** match /cron:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(?!cron)(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

#Remove index.php being displayed on pages
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|attachments|email|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have played around with it a bit but it's still not working. I think this could be because all requests are handled by a index.php file in the root directory and the cron itself is a controller handled by the framework.